# sed '/^Title:/{N;N;N;N;N;s/.*//;x;d;};x;p;${x;p;}' command what will do in a file

Tags: shell, unix, sed

Please help me to understand below mentioned sed command in unix.

```
sed '/^Title:/{N;N;N;N;N;s/.*//;x;d;};x;p;${x;p;}'
```

Comment: First I suggest to read complete man page of `sed`: `man sed`

Comment: Make a test file e.g. `seq 20 >file` and change one line to match the regexp e.g. `sed  -i '10s/^/Title:/' file`. Then run the above against the test file and study the result e.g. `sed '/^Title:/{N;N;N;N;N;s/.*//;x;d;};x;p;${x;p;}' file | sed -n l|cat -n`